# email bouncing back

Tags: exchange-2007

Some emails are bouncing back with the error message below

```
The following organization rejected your message: cluster-m.mailcontrol.com
```

Also when I looked the further details it gives me this information:

```
Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server: myserver.com.au

example.emailadd@domain.com
cluster-m.mailcontrol.com #554 5.7.1 Access denied ##

Received: from myserver.com.au ([192.168.0.3]) by
 myserver.com.au ([192.168.0.3]) with mapi; Mon, 27 Jun 2011
 08:04:50 +0800
From: XYZ <xyz.xyz@mydomain.com>
To: "XYZ (xyz.xyz@externaldomain.com)"
    <xyz.xyz@externaldomain.com>
Date: Mon, 27 Jun 2011 08:04:49 +0800
Subject: FW: Pic S979888
Thread-Topic: Pic S979888
Thread-Index: Acw0WppDIX2PPJwZR0OGVP1rbUtzDAAAzcuA
Message-ID: <573874A6BF36864EA3FB179BF7A43C2B031D388DF7D8@myserver.com.au>
Accept-Language: en-US, en-AU
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
acceptlanguage: en-US, en-AU
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="_004_573874A6BF36864EA3FB179BF7A43C2B031D388DF7D8bunsrvapp00_"
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Could you please tell me what is wrong with this and why is it bouncing back?

Comment: Is cluster-m.mailcontrol.com your own smtp server or the receiving smtp server? Error #554 5.7.1 are usually relaying problems.

Answer (score 2):

The recipient is using Websense's hosted email security service. This service requires a valid DNS PTR record for every address that connects to it. It'd be awesome if they told you that in the error, but they don't. Call your ISP. Have them create the PTR record for you. Everything should work once Websense can look up the PTR for your IP address.

Answer (score 1):

You may find a more specific error in the SMTP logs, located at (Exchange program files)\TransportRoles\Logs\ProtocolLog\SmtpSend. Find the conversation with the remote mail server and you'll see a reason why that message was rejected.

Comment: "554 5.7.1 Access denied"